# Updating MS Access Database in C# Application

Tags: c#, ms-access

thanks in advance for any help or suggestions.

I have found many posts on here which are relating to my issue however I am struggling to find out what exactly I need to change to solve my problem of updating an MS Access database from a C# application. So I apologize if people feel this post is too similar to others.

Here is my update code:

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\DATA2\Nescot Students\Y13\s0234438\dboCanada.accdb";
conn.Open();

string query = "UPDATE Products SET [Product_Name] = @ProName, [Product_Description] = @ProDes, [Standard_Cost] = @StaCos, [Category] = @Cat, [List_Price] = @LisPri  WHERE ID = '" + Convert.ToInt16(lblID.Text) + "'";
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn) /*{ CommandType = CommandType.Text }*/;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProName", txtProducts.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProDes", txtDescription.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StaCos", Convert.ToDecimal(txtPrice.Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cat", txtCat.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LisPri", Convert.ToDecimal(txtListPrice.Text));

int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

I'm sure that I am very close to getting this to work but I don't know where to go from here... The error that is coming up is

> 'Data type mismatch in criteria expression.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
WHERE ID = '" + Convert.ToInt16(lblID.Text) + "'"
```

This is wrong. If your `ID` column is numeric you don't need to use single quotes.

Why don't you add it also as a parameter since you did for the others? Like;

```
..WHERE ID = @id;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.ToInt32(lblID.Text));
```

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `OleDbConnection` and `OleDbCommand`.

```
string ConnString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\DATA2\Nescot Students\Y13\s0234438\dboCanada.accdb";
using(OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnString ))
using(OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
   cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE Products SET [Product_Name] = @ProName, [Product_Description] = @ProDes, [Standard_Cost] = @StaCos, [Category] = @Cat, [List_Price] = @LisPri  WHERE ID = @id";
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProName", txtProducts.Text);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProDes", txtDescription.Text);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StaCos", Convert.ToDecimal(txtPrice.Text));
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cat", txtCat.Text);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LisPri", Convert.ToDecimal(txtListPrice.Text));
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.ToInt32(lblID.Text));

   conn.Open();
   int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Soner, I have now added it as a parameter and it works perfectly. I will mark as an answer as soon as I can (currently saying 'Wait 10 minutes')